# How to get rid of unnecessary url's from google search console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, links, dead-links

66 pages of my website which are all deleted still appears in page report of google search console. [image]My eagerness is knowing all the possibilities. Questions include: 1. does this affect SEO? 2. How can I completely get rid of these url's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: Use Google Search Console
Here's how to remove a URL using Google Search Console: Visit the Remove URLs tool here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal. Select your website under “Please select a property” Click the grey button, enter your URL and click “Continue”

Comment: That is for temporary removal right?

Answer (score 1):

If they are truly deleted they should return a 404 or 410 https status code and not show up as valid/indexed. They should show up as excluded due to their 404 status.

The reports may be delayed.

If they are returning a 404 status, then they will be excluded over time. The URL removal tool can speed that up, but if they are not 404ing the URLs will eventually return.